# What is the best linux mail solution for a dedicated phplist installation?

Tags: linux, postfix-mta, qmail, phplist

I am setting up phplist for a client on my dedicated server.  I am going to install a dedicated mail solution on a dedicated IP address for his mailing list.  He has an estimated 5,000 subscribers interested in his newsletter right now.  The goal is to send out about that many emails per night.

The current obvious choices are qmail and postfix.  Can I get some pros and cons to both?  Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**qmail** can handle that.  DNS will be your main problem for sending into sites like yahoo, godaddy, and gmail for example.  Make sure you are hosted on clean IPs:
http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/

If you use qmail this is a good site:  http://www.qmailrocks.org/

A newsletter going out every night sounds like spam.  Be careful what ISP you host it at, they may suspend your account when they get complaints (there are always complaints about bulk email, even when it is solicited).